# NuGet cross-project dependencies in shared library

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, nuget, .net-core

The setup: I've created a library targeting .Net Standard 2.0 in VS 2017 and this library uses NuGet to reference a 3rd party driver and manage its dependencies. So far, so good.

The next step is to create an application that uses the (shared) library, in this case a console app targeting .Net Core. I can, of course, add a reference to the DLL(s) that form the shared library. That compiles but doesn't run because the 3rd party stuff is missing. I could of course just copy all required DLLs to the application but for obvious reasons I'd rather use NuGet.
I'm not very experienced with NuGet, never used it in this constellation and having read articles like [NuGet cross-project dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664407/) I'm getting the impression I need to fiddle with the application's project file in order to get the library in a complete form but surely that can't be the way forward.

So my question is - is the problem on the side of the library, i.e. do I need to build or export in a particular way, or on the side of the application which, IMHO, shouldn't need to know that level of detail about some library it consumes.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sharing a large, complicated library this way with several other solutions.

First, set up your library. Right click on the library's project name and choose Properties. About halfway down you'll see a tab labeled Packages. You can use that to auto-generate the NuGet package every time you rebuild the project. Just increment the version number. I use four position version numbering -- the first three are [semver-style](https://semver.org/) (major release, minor release, patch release), and the fourth one I increment manually for each new build.

I recommend creating a folder on your drive or network specifically for your local NuGet packages. You can create folders under that for each project. Then you point your debug and release build output to that project folder, and the NuGet package will be generated there, too.

Finally, back in Visual Studio, go to Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources and add that top-level folder as a package source.

From there it's simple -- open your NuGet dependencies in your consuming app. There's a drop-down at the top right where you can choose the package source. It will automatically search all the child folders and find whatever packages you've created. Now when you tweak your library, it's just a single click to update the client apps.

Comment: That was clearly the bit I was missing. Very good and comprehensive answer, thanks a lot!